# trying to list google docs with oauth and gdata objective-c api

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oauth-2.0, gdata

I am trying to connect with google docs using oauth 2.0 protocol. I think the connection is OK because I get the access token. After that I want to list the documents. I added the gdata for objective-c api to my project and I followed the examples but I am not getting any doc. I am just trying to read the firt's doc title and show it but something must be wrong or maybe I am missing something. Any help? Thanks. Here is the code:

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize accessToken;
@synthesize mDocListFeed;
@synthesize mDoclistFetchTicket;


static NSString *const kMyClientID = @"199740745364-22lugf8undgv0rc0ucbfpgsn3v90lfsd.apps.googleusercontent.com";
static NSString *const kMyClientSecret = @"dPFs5D66kLyQIgUNL6igKUoX";
static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"casa";

- (GDataServiceGoogleDocs *)docsService {

  static GDataServiceGoogleDocs* service = nil;

  if (!service) {
    service = [[GDataServiceGoogleDocs alloc] init];

    [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
    [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    [service setIsServiceRetryEnabled:YES];
}

return service;

}



- (void) mifetch {

    GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [self docsService];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;


    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs docsFeedURL];


   ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

    mDoclistFetchTicket = ticket;

}

- (void) ticket: (GDataServiceTicket *) ticket
        finishedWithFeed: (GDataFeedDocList *) feed
            error: (NSError *) error {

mDocListFeed = feed;


GDataEntryDocBase *doc = [[mDocListFeed entries] objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *ttitle = [[doc title] stringValue];
UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"primer doc"
                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"titulo: %@", ttitle]
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertView show];

}


- (void)authorize {

  NSString *scope = @"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds";

// scope for Google+ API

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *windowController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]      initWithScope:scope
                                                                                            clientID:kMyClientID
                                                                                        clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                                                    keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                            delegate:self
                                                    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:windowController animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)autenticarse 
{
[self authorize];
}


- (IBAction)listar
{

[self mifetch];
}


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error
{


if (error != nil)
{
    // Authentication failed
    UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
else
{
    //si error==nil en el callback, entonces la peticion fue autorizada
    // Authentication succeeded

    // Assign the access token to the instance property for later use
    self.accessToken = auth.accessToken;



    // Display the access token to the user
    UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Succeeded"
   message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Access Token: %@ code:%@", auth.accessToken, auth.code]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [[self docsService] setAuthorizer:auth];

}
}


// table view data source methods


//The first thing we have to do is, tell the table view how many rows it should expect and this is done in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection. 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (tableView == tablalistar) {
    return [[mDocListFeed entries] count];
}

return 0;


}


//Now that the table view knows how many rows to display, we need to display the actual text which goes in a table view cell. The table view is made of table rows and rows contains table cell. This is done in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath which is called n number of times, where n is the value returned in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection. The method provides indexPath which is of type NSIndexPath and using this we can find out the current row number the table view is going to display.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tablalistar"];

if (tableView == tablalistar) {



    GDataEntryDocBase *doc = [[mDocListFeed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[doc title] stringValue];


}
 return cell;
}   




@end
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

The scope string is requesting permission only for the Spreadsheet API, but the fetch is for the Documents List API.

The scope for the DocList API is available as `+[GDataServiceGoogleDocs authorizationScope]`

Scopes for multiple services can be combined with `+[GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:]`

Incidentally, the DocList API has been replaced by the [Google Drive API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).